# WSO2 devicemgt connection

Tags: wso2

I have a problem accessing IP:9443/devicemgt. I have 3.6.0 iot server under ubuntu
It goes to devicemgt/welcome then setting up environnement and then error:

> Ops... it seems something went wrong.
>   Refresh the page to retry!

I access iot server from an external IP and I have launched iot-server.sh.
The connction to App store and publisher is ok.
I have seen a post indicating to change the /tec/hosts but it doesn't work. In my etc/hosts, I have tried My_IP mdm-wso2 for example.